# while using window.print() the background colors for table cells not printing

Tags: javascript

while using window.print() the background colors for table cells not printing

Thanks for any help/solution

Comment: Do you use another CSS file when printing? Something like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css"/> in your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using IE, that behavior is controlled by user's settings. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296326/en-us for steps to solve this. (I don't think that a webpage can override this setting)

Edit: It looks that even this feature is buggy, erring on the side of "don't print": http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974128/en-us

Comment: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t162435-keeping-background-colors-in-printing.html

Internet Explorer:
- 'Tools' menu

- 'Internet Options...' menu item

- 'Advanaced' tab

- 'Print background colors and images' checkbox


Mozilla:

- 'File' menu

- 'Page Setup...' menu item

- 'Print Background (colours & images)' checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing: I think the browser is making a decision as to how to print background colors. You can probably override it using CSS. Define print-specific styles by going:

```
@media print {
    /*Styles Here*/
}
```